# Pandas - Multiple stacked bar charts on column values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, stacked-chart

I have a dataframe with 5 columns: `salesman`, `vendor`, `product1`, `product2` and `product3`. The dataframe is similar to below:

[image: Dataframe]

I want to groupby `salesman`, loop through `'salesman'` index and create a separate stacked bar chart for each salesman. For each stacked bar chart, I want x-axis to be the `vendor` and y-axis to stack on column values (i.e. product1/2/3 sales amount). Desired output:

[image: Output]

Have tried several methods combined with for loop but keep getting error. Appreciate any guidance on this one! Thank you.

Comment: Please see [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [edit] your question accordingly, thanks.

Comment: welcome to SO, in order for others to help you need to do you bit and make your data reproducible, see [ask] and [mcve]